# jdbc ssl conection failed

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I've been working on a project on mySQL and i have to create an interface to it in ECLIPSE OXYGEN.The problem is JDBC does not let me create one. I ve been getting the error

> "Fri Jan 12 21:49:19 GMT+02:00 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection
>   without server's identity verification is not recommended. According
>   to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must
>   be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification. SQLException: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

When trying to set SSL as true, i get, SSL IS NOT SUPORTED BY THE SERVER(As a side not SSL is placed as "if available" and still not working). Does somebody know how i can bypass it on JAVA so it doesn;t check for SSL?

Comment: Added quote for error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the problem you didn't set the mysql password.
If you set the mysql password and set the password when connection, it will work.

Comment: Could you explain?(If you are reffering to the password for the account on mysql(root password) i do have one).

Comment: for mysql connection in java, the required parameters are username, password and mysql url with 3306 port. And if you make the password field as '', you will get error. For secure aspects, it's good to set the mysql root password.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to put the password when creating the connection in JDBC.Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you. If you are satisfied, will you vote my answer?